# Factorize the following expression, $f(x) = (x-c)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Take
$$
f(x)=(x-c)^3
$$
How many factors does it have?

I have already tried the different factorizing processeses but I do not get to the answer.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the factorizing processes that you tried, because obviously there is a misunderstanding.

Comment: Please also tell us what "the answer" is supposed to be. This may help explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The factors are $k(x-c)$, $k(x^2-2cx+c^2)$, $k(x^3-3cx^2+3c^2x-c^3)$, and $k$ (for any real non-zero number $k$). So there are infinitely many factors (in fact, any polynomial can be said to have infinitely many factors). If you can't understand why, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: again, this is expanding, not factoring. would refrain from answering until OP has clarified their post

Comment: @CSquared He/she asked for the number of factors, not the factorisation. So I wrote down the factors

Comment: there are three factors, as Righter has noted in the comments below the post.

Comment: @CSquared Actually, any combination of those three is also a factor. And I am Righter (I deleted that comment as it didn't address what was asked)

Comment: Like the factors of $8$ are $1,2,4,8$, not $2,2,2$

Comment: @CSquared: I read "Factorize the following expression" and "I have already tried the different factorizing processese". That makes me believe that the question is about factorization.